# Emake conflicts more in my makefile changes than the standard one?

Tags: clearcase, gnu-make

Recently I did changes in makefile to optimize my feature build time. Though it  reduced my feature build time but impacted the total build time (2 hrs 30 mins to 6 hrs :( ). I compared the emake conflicts results of both the builds (my changes and prior one). Mine is having the 2k conflicts. But the prior one is 62 only. But when I compare the build logs all the data seems to be same. Where am I making the mistakes? Please share your inputs. Thanks in Advance.

Krishna

Comment: Can you check the nature of those conflicts?

Comment: Might also want to mention the nature of the changes? With concrete examples... Did you change make options? make tools? macro's defined centrally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all based on the dependency information you have it in history file. I had the same problem in my build system where make built it fast where emake was sluggish for the same build scripts.

The solution to this issue to generate history file first time by running slow build. emake will generate history file at end of the build. Use this history file which will make your build faster.

emake --history=